# Responsive Image Slide with <ul> and <li>

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4

I have an image gallery with slide using `<ul>` and `<li>` with HTML and some CSS, but on mobile it isn't responsive (as you can see [here](https://espacorodadagua.dx.am), I am using a smartphone).

The image gallery images pull and fade away and move onto the next image.

My question is: How do I make it respond on mobile?

Code:

```css
    .slides {
        padding: 0;
        width: 609px;
        height: 420px;
        display: block;
        margin: 0 auto;
        position: relative;
    }
    
    .slides * {
        user-select: none;
        -ms-user-select: none;
        -moz-user-select: none;
        -khtml-user-select: none;
        -webkit-user-select: none;
        -webkit-touch-callout: none;
    }
    
    .slides input { display: none; }
    
    .slide-container { display: block; }
    
    .slide {
        top: 0;
        opacity: 0;
        width: 609px;
        height: 420px;
        display: block;
        position: absolute;
    
        transform: scale(0);
    
        transition: all .7s ease-in-out;
    }
    
    .slide img {
        width: 100%;
        height: 100%;
    }
    
    .nav label {
        width: 200px;
        height: 100%;
        display: none;
        position: absolute;
    
       opacity: 0;
        z-index: 9;
        cursor: pointer;
    
        transition: opacity .2s;
    
        color: #FFF;
        font-size: 156pt;
        text-align: center;
        line-height: 380px;
        font-family: "Varela Round", sans-serif;
        background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, .3);
        text-shadow: 0px 0px 15px rgb(119, 119, 119);
    }
    
    .slide:hover + .nav label { opacity: 0.5; }
    
    .nav label:hover { opacity: 1; }
    
    .nav .next { right: 0; }
    
    input:checked + .slide-container  .slide {
        opacity: 1;
    
        transform: scale(1);
    
        transition: opacity 1s ease-in-out;
    }
    
    input:checked + .slide-container .nav label { display: block; }
    
    .nav-dots {
     width: 100%;
     bottom: 9px;
     height: 11px;
     display: block;
     position: absolute;
     text-align: center;
    }
    
    .nav-dots .nav-dot {
     top: -5px;
     width: 11px;
     height: 11px;
     margin: 0 4px;
     position: relative;
     border-radius: 100%;
     display: inline-block;
     background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.6);
    }
    
    .nav-dots .nav-dot:hover {
     cursor: pointer;
     background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.8);
    }
    
    input#img-1:checked ~ .nav-dots label#img-dot-1,
    input#img-2:checked ~ .nav-dots label#img-dot-2,
    input#img-3:checked ~ .nav-dots label#img-dot-3,
    input#img-4:checked ~ .nav-dots label#img-dot-4,
    input#img-5:checked ~ .nav-dots label#img-dot-5,
    input#img-6:checked ~ .nav-dots label#img-dot-6,
    input#img-7:checked ~ .nav-dots label#img-dot-7,
    input#img-8:checked ~ .nav-dots label#img-dot-8,
    input#img-9:checked ~ .nav-dots label#img-dot-9,
    input#img-9:checked ~ .nav-dots label#img-dot-10 {
     background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.8);
    }
```

```html
    <ul class="slides">
      <input type="radio" name="radio-btn" id="img-1" checked />
      <li class="slide-container">
    <div class="slide">
     <img src="https://farm1.staticflickr.com/917/42512394395_f66da01120_b.jpg" alt="Foto 1">
          </div>
    <div class="nav">
     <label for="img-6" class="prev">&#x2039;</label>
     <label for="img-2" class="next">&#x203a;</label>
    </div>
      </li>

      <input type="radio" name="radio-btn" id="img-2" />
      <li class="slide-container">
          <div class="slide">
            <img src="https://farm2.staticflickr.com/1765/41608791950_8df0d62b83_b.jpg">
          </div>
    <div class="nav">
     <label for="img-1" class="prev">&#x2039;</label>
     <label for="img-3" class="next">&#x203a;</label>
    </div>
      </li>

      <input type="radio" name="radio-btn" id="img-3" />
      <li class="slide-container">
          <div class="slide">
            <img src="https://farm2.staticflickr.com/1767/42512387675_4c7b2ca42a_b.jpg">
          </div>
    <div class="nav">
     <label for="img-2" class="prev">&#x2039;</label>
     <label for="img-4" class="next">&#x203a;</label>
    </div>
      </li>

      <input type="radio" name="radio-btn" id="img-4" />
      <li class="slide-container">
          <div class="slide">
            <img src="https://farm1.staticflickr.com/845/41608785800_c6d777cfff_b.jpg">
          </div>
    <div class="nav">
     <label for="img-3" class="prev">&#x2039;</label>
     <label for="img-5" class="next">&#x203a;</label>
    </div>
      </li>

      <input type="radio" name="radio-btn" id="img-5" />
      <li class="slide-container">
          <div class="slide">
            <img src="https://farm2.staticflickr.com/1804/42512382475_6f99d41e5a_b.jpg">
          </div>
    <div class="nav">
     <label for="img-4" class="prev">&#x2039;</label>
     <label for="img-6" class="next">&#x203a;</label>
    </div>
      </li>

      <input type="radio" name="radio-btn" id="img-6" />
      <li class="slide-container">
          <div class="slide">
            <img src="https://farm2.staticflickr.com/1825/28546926367_cf2647dddf_b.jpg">
          </div>
    <div class="nav">
     <label for="img-5" class="prev">&#x2039;</label>
     <label for="img-7" class="next">&#x203a;</label>
    </div>
      </li>

      <input type="radio" name="radio-btn" id="img-7" />
      <li class="slide-container">
          <div class="slide">
            <img src="https://farm1.staticflickr.com/921/43369027842_f8d9176a13_b.jpg">
          </div>
    <div class="nav">
     <label for="img-6" class="prev">&#x2039;</label>
     <label for="img-8" class="next">&#x203a;</label>
    </div>
      </li>

      <input type="radio" name="radio-btn" id="img-8" />
      <li class="slide-container">
          <div class="slide">
            <img src="https://farm1.staticflickr.com/921/42700036144_d33a9f7e6e_b.jpg">
          </div>
      <div class="nav">
        <label for="img-7" class="prev">&#x2039;</label>
        <label for="img-9" class="next">&#x203a;</label>
      </div>
      </li>

      <input type="radio" name="radio-btn" id="img-9" />
      <li class="slide-container">
          <div class="slide">
            <img src="https://farm2.staticflickr.com/1788/43369022132_f60e412b42_b.jpg">
          </div>
    <div class="nav">
     <label for="img-8" class="prev">&#x2039;</label>
     <label for="img-9" class="next">&#x203a;</label>
    </div>
      </li>

      <input type="radio" name="radio-btn" id="img-10" />
      <li class="slide-container">
          <div class="slide">
            <img src="https://farm1.staticflickr.com/837/29546173958_517b50a57f_b.jpg">
          </div>
      <div class="nav">
        <label for="img-9" class="prev">&#x2039;</label>
        <label for="img-1" class="next">&#x203a;</label>
      </div>
      </li>

      <li class="nav-dots">
        <label for="img-1" class="nav-dot" id="img-dot-1"></label>
        <label for="img-2" class="nav-dot" id="img-dot-2"></label>
        <label for="img-3" class="nav-dot" id="img-dot-3"></label>
        <label for="img-4" class="nav-dot" id="img-dot-4"></label>
        <label for="img-5" class="nav-dot" id="img-dot-5"></label>
        <label for="img-6" class="nav-dot" id="img-dot-6"></label>
        <label for="img-6" class="nav-dot" id="img-dot-7"></label>
        <label for="img-6" class="nav-dot" id="img-dot-8"></label>
        <label for="img-6" class="nav-dot" id="img-dot-9"></label>
        <label for="img-6" class="nav-dot" id="img-dot-10"></label>
      </li>
  </ul>
```

---

Can anyone help me with this problem? I would appreciate it.

---

(Gist [here](https://gist.github.com/losreis/cf0a323925433e81de6d3817d7b5b63e):))

Comment: The CSS from your Gist wasn't really all that long, so pulled it into your question. You want your question to be "complete", as much as possible. If you haven't yet, it's good to read this Help topic: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: What are you trying to use the radio buttons for? As-is, your markup is invalid, as `<li>` is the only allowable immediate child of an `<ol>` or `<ul>` element.

Comment: Example: You click on radio button 4... And the gallery goes to image 4.

Comment: That's actually already baked into Bootstrap's carousel (see http://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.1/components/carousel/#with-indicators) - is using the carousel plugin an option?

Comment: Yes, I can carousel plugin... I just need to study a little how it works and start again :p

Comment: Not to say that you can't use your own slider, but if you're already using Bootstrap, they've already worked through a lot of the issues you're probably running into.

Comment: Carousel looks like a way too easy to use... And looks more beautiful (***)

Answer (score 0):

As far as I am concerned you can make any of the images from your code, responsive, by just adding the following code to them:(you dont even have to use css)

```
 <img src="example.jpg" style="max-width:100%;width:auto;height:auto;max-height:100%;">
```

Answer (score 0):

I am sorry that my previous answer did not work for you, as I want to help you, I think that the code that I let you before could work now if you add this at the beginning of your code in the head part:

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, user-scalable=no, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, minimum-scale=1.0">
```

Comment: Using this code my website, my `<footer>` code come to back of mt gallery, but it worked to make responsive... 
Now I just need to fix this `<footer>` issue. (You can see a super live test here: http://espacorodadagua.dx.am/)
(I hope you got my english heh)

Comment: You should edit your first answer instead of posting 2.